# Undo registry edit change

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry, fonts

I was interested in changing the default font on my Windows 10 devices, and so I followed some instructions I found [here](https://www.laptopmag.com/articles/change-default-font-windows-10). Upon restarting my computer, I realized that the font I chose would not work and I would now like to revert everything back to how it was before.

---

I edited, as per the link above's instructions, in:

```
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts
```

Most of the `Segoe UI <somevariant>` fonts to simply be empty, and then in:

```
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\FontSubstitutes
```

I changed the `Segoe UI` key to my desired font (which was Open Sans).

---

So, how would I revert these changes? I'm guessing that I should revert these values back to their defaults, but I don't know what those defaults are. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Note for the future: back up the registry before you modify it. Then, you can restore the registry if a problem occurs. 

For more information see [How to back up and restore the registry in Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/322756)

Answer (score 0):

Registry entries Copied from Windows 10 1909 Build 18363.836

Here are the default registry entries for both locations you gave, copy the text in between the *** to a text file, then save it, now change the txt file extension to .reg, once that is done right click and select Merge. There are 2 of these below you need to make.

---

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts]

"Arial (TrueType)"="arial.ttf"

"Arial Black (TrueType)"="ariblk.ttf"

"Arial Bold (TrueType)"="arialbd.ttf"

"Arial Bold Italic (TrueType)"="arialbi.ttf"

"Arial Italic (TrueType)"="ariali.ttf"

"Bahnschrift (TrueType)"="bahnschrift.ttf"

"Calibri (TrueType)"="calibri.ttf"

"Calibri Bold (TrueType)"="calibrib.ttf"

"Calibri Bold Italic (TrueType)"="calibriz.ttf"

"Calibri Italic (TrueType)"="calibrii.ttf"

"Calibri Light (TrueType)"="calibril.ttf"

"Calibri Light Italic (TrueType)"="calibrili.ttf"

"Cambria & Cambria Math (TrueType)"="cambria.ttc"

"Cambria Bold (TrueType)"="cambriab.ttf"

"Cambria Bold Italic (TrueType)"="cambriaz.ttf"

"Cambria Italic (TrueType)"="cambriai.ttf"

"Candara (TrueType)"="candara.ttf"

"Candara Bold (TrueType)"="candarab.ttf"

"Candara Bold Italic (TrueType)"="candaraz.ttf"

"Candara Italic (TrueType)"="candarai.ttf"

"Candara Light (TrueType)"="candaral.ttf"

"Candara Light Italic (TrueType)"="candarali.ttf"

"Comic Sans MS (TrueType)"="comic.ttf"

"Comic Sans MS Bold (TrueType)"="comicbd.ttf"

"Comic Sans MS Bold Italic (TrueType)"="comicz.ttf"

"Comic Sans MS Italic (TrueType)"="comici.ttf"

"Consolas (TrueType)"="consola.ttf"

"Consolas Bold (TrueType)"="consolab.ttf"

"Consolas Bold Italic (TrueType)"="consolaz.ttf"

"Consolas Italic (TrueType)"="consolai.ttf"

"Constantia (TrueType)"="constan.ttf"

"Constantia Bold (TrueType)"="constanb.ttf"

"Constantia Bold Italic (TrueType)"="constanz.ttf"

"Constantia Italic (TrueType)"="constani.ttf"

"Corbel (TrueType)"="corbel.ttf"

"Corbel Bold (TrueType)"="corbelb.ttf"

"Corbel Bold Italic (TrueType)"="corbelz.ttf"

"Corbel Italic (TrueType)"="corbeli.ttf"

"Corbel Light (TrueType)"="corbell.ttf"

"Corbel Light Italic (TrueType)"="corbelli.ttf"

"Courier New (TrueType)"="cour.ttf"

"Courier New Bold (TrueType)"="courbd.ttf"

"Courier New Bold Italic (TrueType)"="courbi.ttf"

"Courier New Italic (TrueType)"="couri.ttf"

"Ebrima (TrueType)"="ebrima.ttf"

"Ebrima Bold (TrueType)"="ebrimabd.ttf"

"Franklin Gothic Medium (TrueType)"="framd.ttf"

"Franklin Gothic Medium Italic (TrueType)"="framdit.ttf"

"Gabriola (TrueType)"="Gabriola.ttf"

"Gadugi (TrueType)"="gadugi.ttf"

"Gadugi Bold (TrueType)"="gadugib.ttf"

"Georgia (TrueType)"="georgia.ttf"

"Georgia Bold (TrueType)"="georgiab.ttf"

"Georgia Bold Italic (TrueType)"="georgiaz.ttf"

"Georgia Italic (TrueType)"="georgiai.ttf"

"Impact (TrueType)"="impact.ttf"

"Ink Free (TrueType)"="Inkfree.ttf"

"Javanese Text (TrueType)"="javatext.ttf"

"Leelawadee UI (TrueType)"="leelawui.ttf"

"Leelawadee UI Bold (TrueType)"="leelauib.ttf"

"Leelawadee UI Semilight (TrueType)"="leeluisl.ttf"

"Lucida Console (TrueType)"="lucon.TTF"

"Lucida Sans Unicode (TrueType)"="l_10646.ttf"

"Malgun Gothic (TrueType)"="malgun.ttf"

"Malgun Gothic Bold (TrueType)"="malgunbd.ttf"

"Malgun Gothic SemiLight (TrueType)"="malgunsl.ttf"

"Microsoft Himalaya (TrueType)"="himalaya.ttf"

"Microsoft JhengHei & Microsoft JhengHei UI (TrueType)"="msjh.ttc"

"Microsoft JhengHei Bold & Microsoft JhengHei UI Bold (TrueType)"="msjhbd.ttc"

"Microsoft JhengHei Light & Microsoft JhengHei UI Light (TrueType)"="msjhl.ttc"

"Microsoft New Tai Lue (TrueType)"="ntailu.ttf"

"Microsoft New Tai Lue Bold (TrueType)"="ntailub.ttf"

"Microsoft PhagsPa (TrueType)"="phagspa.ttf"

"Microsoft PhagsPa Bold (TrueType)"="phagspab.ttf"

"Microsoft Sans Serif (TrueType)"="micross.ttf"

"Microsoft Tai Le (TrueType)"="taile.ttf"

"Microsoft Tai Le Bold (TrueType)"="taileb.ttf"

"Microsoft YaHei & Microsoft YaHei UI (TrueType)"="msyh.ttc"

"Microsoft YaHei Bold & Microsoft YaHei UI Bold (TrueType)"="msyhbd.ttc"

"Microsoft YaHei Light & Microsoft YaHei UI Light (TrueType)"="msyhl.ttc"

"Microsoft Yi Baiti (TrueType)"="msyi.ttf"

"MingLiU-ExtB & PMingLiU-ExtB & MingLiU_HKSCS-ExtB (TrueType)"="mingliub.ttc"

"Modern (All res)"="modern.fon"

"Mongolian Baiti (TrueType)"="monbaiti.ttf"

"MS Gothic & MS UI Gothic & MS PGothic (TrueType)"="msgothic.ttc"

"MV Boli (TrueType)"="mvboli.ttf"

"Myanmar Text (TrueType)"="mmrtext.ttf"

"Myanmar Text Bold (TrueType)"="mmrtextb.ttf"

"Nirmala UI (TrueType)"="Nirmala.ttf"

"Nirmala UI Bold (TrueType)"="NirmalaB.ttf"

"Nirmala UI Semilight (TrueType)"="NirmalaS.ttf"

"Palatino Linotype (TrueType)"="pala.ttf"

"Palatino Linotype Bold (TrueType)"="palab.ttf"

"Palatino Linotype Bold Italic (TrueType)"="palabi.ttf"

"Palatino Linotype Italic (TrueType)"="palai.ttf"

"Roman (All res)"="roman.fon"

"Script (All res)"="script.fon"

"Segoe MDL2 Assets (TrueType)"="segmdl2.ttf"

"Segoe Print (TrueType)"="segoepr.ttf"

"Segoe Print Bold (TrueType)"="segoeprb.ttf"

"Segoe Script (TrueType)"="segoesc.ttf"

"Segoe Script Bold (TrueType)"="segoescb.ttf"

"Segoe UI (TrueType)"="segoeui.ttf"

"Segoe UI Black (TrueType)"="seguibl.ttf"

"Segoe UI Black Italic (TrueType)"="seguibli.ttf"

"Segoe UI Bold (TrueType)"="segoeuib.ttf"

"Segoe UI Bold Italic (TrueType)"="segoeuiz.ttf"

"Segoe UI Emoji (TrueType)"="seguiemj.ttf"

"Segoe UI Historic (TrueType)"="seguihis.ttf"

"Segoe UI Italic (TrueType)"="segoeuii.ttf"

"Segoe UI Light (TrueType)"="segoeuil.ttf"

"Segoe UI Light Italic (TrueType)"="seguili.ttf"

"Segoe UI Semibold (TrueType)"="seguisb.ttf"

"Segoe UI Semibold Italic (TrueType)"="seguisbi.ttf"

"Segoe UI Semilight (TrueType)"="segoeuisl.ttf"

"Segoe UI Semilight Italic (TrueType)"="seguisli.ttf"

"Segoe UI Symbol (TrueType)"="seguisym.ttf"

"SimSun & NSimSun (TrueType)"="simsun.ttc"

"SimSun-ExtB (TrueType)"="simsunb.ttf"

"Sitka Small & Sitka Text & Sitka Subheading & Sitka Heading & Sitka Display & Sitka 
Banner (TrueType)"="Sitka.ttc"

"Sitka Small Bold & Sitka Text Bold & Sitka Subheading Bold & Sitka Heading Bold & Sitka 
Display Bold & Sitka Banner Bold (TrueType)"="SitkaB.ttc"

"Sitka Small Bold Italic & Sitka Text Bold Italic & Sitka Subheading Bold Italic & Sitka 
Heading Bold Italic & Sitka Display Bold Italic & Sitka Banner Bold Italic 
(TrueType)"="SitkaZ.ttc"

"Sitka Small Italic & Sitka Text Italic & Sitka Subheading Italic & Sitka Heading Italic & 
Sitka Display Italic & Sitka Banner Italic (TrueType)"="SitkaI.ttc"

"Sylfaen (TrueType)"="sylfaen.ttf"

"Symbol (TrueType)"="symbol.ttf"

"Tahoma (TrueType)"="tahoma.ttf"

"Tahoma Bold (TrueType)"="tahomabd.ttf"

"Times New Roman (TrueType)"="times.ttf"

"Times New Roman Bold (TrueType)"="timesbd.ttf"

"Times New Roman Bold Italic (TrueType)"="timesbi.ttf"

"Times New Roman Italic (TrueType)"="timesi.ttf"

"Trebuchet MS (TrueType)"="trebuc.ttf"

"Trebuchet MS Bold (TrueType)"="trebucbd.ttf"

"Trebuchet MS Bold Italic (TrueType)"="trebucbi.ttf"

"Trebuchet MS Italic (TrueType)"="trebucit.ttf"

"Verdana (TrueType)"="verdana.ttf"

"Verdana Bold (TrueType)"="verdanab.ttf"

"Verdana Bold Italic (TrueType)"="verdanaz.ttf"

"Verdana Italic (TrueType)"="verdanai.ttf"

"Webdings (TrueType)"="webdings.ttf"

"Wingdings (TrueType)"="wingding.ttf"

"Yu Gothic Bold & Yu Gothic UI Semibold & Yu Gothic UI Bold (TrueType)"="YuGothB.ttc"

"Yu Gothic Light & Yu Gothic UI Light (TrueType)"="YuGothL.ttc"

"Yu Gothic Medium & Yu Gothic UI Regular (TrueType)"="YuGothM.ttc"

"Yu Gothic Regular & Yu Gothic UI Semilight (TrueType)"="YuGothR.ttc"

"Courier 10,12,15"="COURE.FON"

"Courier 10,12,15 (120)"="COURF.FON"

"MS Serif 8,10,12,14,18,24"="SERIFE.FON"

"MS Serif 8,10,12,14,18,24 (120)"="SERIFF.FON"

"MS Sans Serif 8,10,12,14,18,24"="SSERIFE.FON"

"MS Sans Serif 8,10,12,14,18,24 (120)"="SSERIFF.FON"

"Small Fonts"="SMALLE.FON"

"Small Fonts (120)"="SMALLF.FON"

"Holo MDL2 Assets (TrueType)"="holomdl2.ttf"

"MT Extra (TrueType)"="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Common Files\\Microsoft Shared\\EQUATION\\MTEXTRA.TTF"

"Book Antiqua Bold (TrueType)"="ANTQUAB.TTF"

"Book Antiqua Bold Italic (TrueType)"="ANTQUABI.TTF"

"Book Antiqua Italic (TrueType)"="ANTQUAI.TTF"

"Book Antiqua (TrueType)"="BKANT.TTF"

"Century Gothic (TrueType)"="GOTHIC.TTF"

"Century Gothic Bold (TrueType)"="GOTHICB.TTF"

"Century Gothic Bold Italic (TrueType)"="GOTHICBI.TTF"

"Century Gothic Italic (TrueType)"="GOTHICI.TTF"

"Bookshelf Symbol 7 (TrueType)"="BSSYM7.TTF"

"MS Reference Sans Serif (TrueType)"="REFSAN.TTF"

"MS Reference Specialty (TrueType)"="REFSPCL.TTF"

"Freestyle Script (TrueType)"="FREESCPT.TTF"

"Juice ITC (TrueType)"="JUICE___.TTF"

"Kristen ITC (TrueType)"="ITCKRIST.TTF"

"Lucida Handwriting Italic (TrueType)"="LHANDW.TTF"

"Mistral (TrueType)"="MISTRAL.TTF"

"Tempus Sans ITC (TrueType)"="TEMPSITC.TTF"

"Garamond (TrueType)"="GARA.TTF"

"Garamond Bold (TrueType)"="GARABD.TTF"

"Garamond Italic (TrueType)"="GARAIT.TTF"

"Monotype Corsiva (TrueType)"="MTCORSVA.TTF"

"Bookman Old Style (TrueType)"="BOOKOS.TTF"

"Bookman Old Style Bold (TrueType)"="BOOKOSB.TTF"

"Bookman Old Style Bold Italic (TrueType)"="BOOKOSBI.TTF"

"Bookman Old Style Italic (TrueType)"="BOOKOSI.TTF"

"Algerian (TrueType)"="ALGER.TTF"

"Baskerville Old Face (TrueType)"="BASKVILL.TTF"

"Bauhaus 93 (TrueType)"="BAUHS93.TTF"

"Bell MT (TrueType)"="BELL.TTF"

"Bell MT Bold (TrueType)"="BELLB.TTF"

"Bell MT Italic (TrueType)"="BELLI.TTF"

"Berlin Sans FB Bold (TrueType)"="BRLNSB.TTF"

"Berlin Sans FB Demi Bold (TrueType)"="BRLNSDB.TTF"

"Berlin Sans FB (TrueType)"="BRLNSR.TTF"

"Bernard MT Condensed (TrueType)"="BERNHC.TTF"

"Bodoni MT Poster Compressed (TrueType)"="BOD_PSTC.TTF"

"Britannic Bold (TrueType)"="BRITANIC.TTF"

"Broadway (TrueType)"="BROADW.TTF"

"Brush Script MT Italic (TrueType)"="BRUSHSCI.TTF"

"Californian FB Bold (TrueType)"="CALIFB.TTF"

"Californian FB Italic (TrueType)"="CALIFI.TTF"

"Californian FB (TrueType)"="CALIFR.TTF"

"Centaur (TrueType)"="CENTAUR.TTF"

"Chiller (TrueType)"="CHILLER.TTF"

"Colonna MT (TrueType)"="COLONNA.TTF"

"Cooper Black (TrueType)"="COOPBL.TTF"

"Footlight MT Light (TrueType)"="FTLTLT.TTF"

"Harlow Solid Italic (TrueType)"="HARLOWSI.TTF"

"Harrington (TrueType)"="HARNGTON.TTF"

"High Tower Text (TrueType)"="HTOWERT.TTF"

"High Tower Text Italic (TrueType)"="HTOWERTI.TTF"

"Jokerman (TrueType)"="JOKERMAN.TTF"

"Kunstler Script (TrueType)"="KUNSTLER.TTF"

"Lucida Bright (TrueType)"="LBRITE.TTF"

"Lucida Bright Demibold (TrueType)"="LBRITED.TTF"

"Lucida Bright Demibold Italic (TrueType)"="LBRITEDI.TTF"

"Lucida Bright Italic (TrueType)"="LBRITEI.TTF"

"Lucida Calligraphy Italic (TrueType)"="LCALLIG.TTF"

"Lucida Fax Regular (TrueType)"="LFAX.TTF"

"Lucida Fax Demibold (TrueType)"="LFAXD.TTF"

"Lucida Fax Demibold Italic (TrueType)"="LFAXDI.TTF"

"Lucida Fax Italic (TrueType)"="LFAXI.TTF"

"Magneto Bold (TrueType)"="MAGNETOB.TTF"

"Matura MT Script Capitals (TrueType)"="MATURASC.TTF"

"Modern No. 20 (TrueType)"="MOD20.TTF"

"Niagara Engraved (TrueType)"="NIAGENG.TTF"

"Niagara Solid (TrueType)"="NIAGSOL.TTF"

"Old English Text MT (TrueType)"="OLDENGL.TTF"

"Onyx (TrueType)"="ONYX.TTF"

"Parchment (TrueType)"="PARCHM.TTF"

"Playbill (TrueType)"="PLAYBILL.TTF"

"Poor Richard (TrueType)"="POORICH.TTF"

"Ravie (TrueType)"="RAVIE.TTF"

"Informal Roman (TrueType)"="INFROMAN.TTF"

"Showcard Gothic (TrueType)"="SHOWG.TTF"

"Snap ITC (TrueType)"="SNAP____.TTF"

"Stencil (TrueType)"="STENCIL.TTF"

"Viner Hand ITC (TrueType)"="VINERITC.TTF"

"Vivaldi Italic (TrueType)"="VIVALDII.TTF"

"Vladimir Script (TrueType)"="VLADIMIR.TTF"

"Wide Latin (TrueType)"="LATINWD.TTF"

"Century (TrueType)"="CENTURY.TTF"

"Wingdings 2 (TrueType)"="WINGDNG2.TTF"

"Wingdings 3 (TrueType)"="WINGDNG3.TTF"

"Arial Unicode MS (TrueType)"="ARIALUNI.TTF"

"MS Mincho (TrueType)"="MSMINCHO.TTF"

"Arial Narrow (TrueType)"="ARIALN.TTF"

"Arial Narrow Bold (TrueType)"="ARIALNB.TTF"

"Arial Narrow Bold Italic (TrueType)"="ARIALNBI.TTF"

"Arial Narrow Italic (TrueType)"="ARIALNI.TTF"
```

---

.

---

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\FontSubstitutes]

"Arabic Transparent"="Arial"

"Arabic Transparent Bold"="Arial Bold"

"Arabic Transparent Bold,0"="Arial Bold,178"

"Arabic Transparent,0"="Arial,178"

"Arial Baltic,186"="Arial,186"

"Arial CE,238"="Arial,238"

"Arial CYR,204"="Arial,204"

"Arial Greek,161"="Arial,161"

"Arial TUR,162"="Arial,162"

"Courier New Baltic,186"="Courier New,186"

"Courier New CE,238"="Courier New,238"

"Courier New CYR,204"="Courier New,204"

"Courier New Greek,161"="Courier New,161"

"Courier New TUR,162"="Courier New,162"

"Helv"="MS Sans Serif"

"Helvetica"="Arial"

"MS Shell Dlg 2"="Tahoma"

"Tahoma Armenian"="Tahoma"

"Times"="Times New Roman"

"Times New Roman Baltic,186"="Times New Roman,186"

"Times New Roman CE,238"="Times New Roman,238"

"Times New Roman CYR,204"="Times New Roman,204"

"Times New Roman Greek,161"="Times New Roman,161"

"Times New Roman TUR,162"="Times New Roman,162"

"Tms Rmn"="MS Serif"

"MS Shell Dlg"="Microsoft Sans Serif"
```

---